# Layer not visible if not identified

Tags: geonetwork

I'm trying to create a record that allows you to view the content, even if you are not identified.
If I check the privileges "All", I can see the link to the map, but the data is not displayed: WMS getCapabilities requests have failed.

What should be done to make data visible to all, guests, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right. To make publicly available a record you need to grant the *Publish* permission to the group *All*:

[image]

If it isn't working maybe there could be an error in the format or names of the online resource added to the metadata record.

Comment: Yes I granted the Publish permission to the group All.
My layer is visible is the search bar, but when I try to display :

"Les demandes getCapabilities du WMS ont échouées, L'url http://****:8080/geoserver/administratif/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities a retourné le status ''. Vous devez vérifier l'url ou vérifier que le service est en actif."

This Geoserver URL is OK because in QGIS I can display datas.

In Geonetwork, to add the layer, I tried the different protocols :
- OGC Web Map Service
- OGC WMS Capabilities service

Comment: the problem recurs on different layers, so I guess there is something I'm doing wrong, but I can't find what...

Comment: And same problem on sample records (Hydrological Basins in Africa).
"Les demandes getCapabilities du WMS ont échouées, L'url http://data.fao.org/maps/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities a retourné le status '403'. Vous devez vérifier l'url ou vérifier que le service est en actif."

The problem may come from my server, right?

Comment: Maybe it's a CORS problem. Try to go to Admin console -> Statistics and Status -> Record links analysis -> Analyze all records and wait until the analysis has finished. This should register the existing links in the catalog and allow the use of GN built-in proxy to retrieve the data even if the remote server doesn't send the right CORS headers.

Comment: The links analysis gives nothing. My layer isn't listed...
We're onto something!

Comment: Yes, it was a CORS problem. I enabled CORS in wb.xml file, and now it's OK !
Thanks